# yo: command not found when running yeoman angular generator

Tags: node.js, angularjs, bash, npm, yeoman

I've read every related question on SO and can't get yeoman to work. I'm trying to run the yeoman angular generator with `yo angular` but I continue to get the error:

`yo: command not found`

I'm sure it has something to do with my .bash_profile, which looks like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export GITAWAREPROMPT=~/.bash/git-aware-prompt
source $GITAWAREPROMPT/main.sh
export PS1="\u@\h \w \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ "

export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/Users/jamesontrinker/npm/lib/node_modules"
```

I'm pretty ignorant regarding proper paths and all that. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add your npm packages to your `PATH`. They're put in a different place then `/usr/local/bin` and even if npm can see it, that doesn't necessarily mean your command line can.

Comment: Did you install yeoman with `global` (`-g`) flag?

Comment: Can you show me what that looks like? I'm not completely following.

Comment: I did install with -g

Comment: Did you install both `yo` and `generator-angular`?

Answer (score -1):

If you install yo with -g, there should be a static link created in `/usr/bin`
Looks like this: `/usr/bin/yo -> /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js`

So as long as you have `/usr/bin` in the `$PATH`, yo should work.

Comment: Does my .bash_profile look correct? Because yo isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure about your .bash_profile, because $PATH maybe set by .profile or .bashrc. If you do `echo $PATH`, check if `/usr/bin` is in your $PATH

Comment: echo $PATH: `/Users/jamesontinker/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
jamesontinker@jamesons-imac`

Comment: I believe it's `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin`. It's probably another issue. Did you reload your shell since then?

Comment: What about the output of `ls -al /usr/bin | grep node_`. And `ls /usr/lib/node_modules/`

Comment: According to [`npm-folders`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html), npm packages should be installed in the directory where node is located.

Comment: `ls -al /usr/bin | grep node_` doesn't return anything. And `ls /usr/lib/node_modules/` returns No such file or directory.

Comment: Check where the `node` locates. `which node`. And find the `node_modules` folder

Comment: which node returns `/usr/local/bin/node`. And which node_modules returns nothing.